# Trying to resolve CORS error on put request in localhost

Tags: http, cors, ballerina

When using PUT method I'm getting this error.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Ballerina server doesn't identify my put request as the corresponding resource.

This is my ballerina service code:

```
import ballerina/http;

@http:ServiceConfig {
    cors: {
        allowOrigins: ["http://localhost:3000"],
        allowMethods:["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"]
    }
}

service /projects on new http:Listener(8080) {


    isolated resource function post .(@http:Payload Project project) returns int|error? {
        return addProject(project);
    }

    isolated resource function get [int id]() returns Project|error? {
        return getProject(id);
    }

    isolated resource function get .() returns Project[]|error? {
        return getAllProjects();
    }

    isolated resource function put .(@http:Payload Project project) returns int|error? {
        return updateProject(project);
    }

    isolated resource function delete [int id]() returns int|error? {
        return removeProject(id);
    }

}
```

I'm not receiving the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when making a `preflight` request to this PUT resource: `/projects/1`. This is the actual response I'm receiving from this service:

```bash
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
allow: GET, DELETE, OPTIONS
content-length: 0
server: ballerina
date: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 11:03:14 +0530, 0B
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected as there is no resource matching `projects/1` in your service. If you are referring to this PUT resource:

```
isolated resource function put .(@http:Payload Project project) returns int|error? {
     return updateProject(project);
}
```

Then this is not bind to `/projects/[id]`, this is actually bind to `/projects`(more info can be found [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-service-and-resource-paths/)). Since the requested resource does not exist you are not getting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

If you change your resource like this then it should work:

```
isolated resource function put [int id](@http:Payload Project project) returns int|error? {
     return updateProject(project);
}
```